# Continuous extensions of Riemann mappings

Tags: gn.general-topology, cv.complex-variables

Let $K$ be a compact set in $\mathbb C$ without interior. Suppose, additionally, that $K$ is  a retract (or equivalently $K$ connected, $K$ locally connected and $\mathbb C\setminus K$ connected).  Then
  $G:=S_2\setminus K$ is a simply connected domain in the Riemann sphere $S_2\sim \widehat{\mathbb C}$. It is known that under these conditions any Riemann map  $f$ from the exterior (within $S_2$) of the closed unit disk $D$  onto $G$ with $f(\infty)=\infty$ has a continuous extension $F$ to the unit circle $\mathbb T$ with $K=F(\mathbb T)$. Can this be deduced from  the "usual" version of bounded simply connected domains whose boundary is a curve? This is easy if $K$ has interior points. Note that the usual "trick" in the proof of Riemann's mapping theorem by considering on $G$ functions of the form $\sqrt{1/ (w-a)}$, $a\in K$,  gives a priori no information on the boundaries (which get split). Why local connectedness of the boundaries is an invariant?

Answer (score 2):

This is true, and can be proved as you suggest, and a convenient reference is Milnor,
Dynamics in one complex variable. The conditions you stated are necessary and sufficient for the conformal map to be continuous in the closed disk.

Remark on terminology. This function is the inverse to the Riemann map.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see an answer in Milnor to my first question, as already the general case is proved there. Also, the invariance of local connectedness is an a posteriori fact there? Isn'it?

Comment: @ray: yes, it is. And it actually follows from Milnor's statement. But of course there must be also a pure topological proof.

Comment: Does anyone know such a direct proof that square-root functions $\sqrt{z-b}$ map simply connected domains  $U$ with locally connected boundary to the same class of domains whenever $b\in\partial U$?